# How to exclude all shades of gray while generating random hex color code?

Tags: javascript

I am generating random color codes using this:

```
var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    if( color.length === 5 )
    {
        color.concat('0');
    }
```

But I want to exclude all shades of gray color from this. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why? Do you want only bright colours, or is it only extremely literal RGB greys that are disallowed (not `#222223`, for example)? Are you generating some kind of colour scheme?

Comment: @Ryan only rgb grays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to limit the range of one color part to only 100 different values instead of 256 for 2 out of three color parts, and then add some constant to it (i.e. a shift).

To picture the 3 ranges for the three color parts:

```
********************
************************************************
                            ********************
|                  |        |                  |
0                 100      156                256
```

Then you would assign each of those three numbers to the RGB components, but also randomly, so that the first value could be used for either the R, G, B component, the second for the two remaining ones, and the third for the one left over.

The closest a color can come to a grey scale is when the first color part is maximised (99), the last one minimised (156), and the middle one is half way those values (128). If that color is not grey to you, then this scheme will be OK. Otherwise you could decrease the size of the two shorter ranges as needed.

This leads to the following code:

```js
function randomColor() {
    const rangeSize = 100; // adapt as needed
    const parts = [
        Math.floor(Math.random()*256),
        Math.floor(Math.random()*rangeSize),
        Math.floor(Math.random()*rangeSize) + 256-rangeSize 
    ].sort( (a, b) => Math.random() < 0.5 );

    return parts.map( p => p.toString(16).padStart(2, "0") ).join('');
}

// Sample
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (const div of divs) {
    div.style.background = '#' + randomColor();
}
```

```css
#container div {
   height: 20px; width: 60px;
   margin: 1px;
   display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<span id="container">
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> 
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</span>
```

You can experiment with the size of the two shorter ranges: they now have a size of 100, but you can make them smaller to exclude more colors which you may still find too "greyish". You would need to adapt the constant `rangeSize` accordingly.

### Alternative

The above will exclude some colors which you might still find interesting to get, for instance colors with values for R, G and B which are all above 100, but do not result in a (light) grey-like color. If you really want to be able to get *any* color that is not too much grey, then you could:

- Generate all three color parts randomly
- If they are not too close together, then return this as the result, otherwise:
- Taking the two extreme values, determine the allowable ranges that the middle one should be relocated to to make it an acceptable color
- Generate a random value that stays within those acceptable ranges

The case where the color parts are too close together can be depicted as follows:

```
        *   *    *
      |-------------|      
|                                |
0                               255
```

The hyphens show the minimum distance the outermost values must have, and so the middle value will be relocated. It must be put outside the following two ranges:

```
        *        *
   |-------------|                 (forbidden)
        |-------------|            (forbidden)
|                                |
0                               255
```

And so must go in either of the following ranges:

```
        *        *
|--|                  |----------| (allowed)

|                                |
0                               255
```

This relocation can be done by taking a random value from a range that is as long as the two ranges together, and then checking whether that random value falls within the first range. If not, the gap between the two is added to it.

Here is how that could be coded:

```js
function randomColor() {
    // Threshold can be between 0 and 127: 
    //    the higher it is, the more colors are considered to be too grey-like.
    const threshold = 50;
    // Generate three color parts randomly
    const parts = Array.from(Array(3), _ => 
            Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
        ).sort( (a, b) => a-b );
    
    // Check whether they are too close to the same value:
    if (parts[2] - parts[0] < threshold) { // color is too greyish
        // Replace the middle one with a random value outside of the "too close" range
        const exclude = Math.min(255, parts[0] + threshold) 
                      - Math.max(0, parts[2] - threshold);
        parts[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*(256-exclude));
        if (parts[1] >= parts[2] - threshold) parts[1] += exclude;
    }
    // Shuffle and format the color parts and return the resulting string
    return parts
        .sort( (a, b) => Math.random() < 0.5 )
        .map( p => p.toString(16).padStart(2, "0") )
        .join('');
}

// Sample
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (const div of divs) {
    div.style.background = '#' + randomColor();
    console.log(div.style.background);
}
```

```css
#container div {
   height: 20px; width: 60px;
   margin: 1px;
   display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<span id="container">
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> 
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</span>
```

Like in the first solution there is a value you can change to influence the sensitivity. The higher it is, the further away the relocated color part must be from the other two parts.

Comment: Note that after you accepted this answer, I still improved it allowing one color part to be unrestricted, and only limit the two others. That should be enough.

Comment: I like your answer but I'm still not fully satisfied with it. I'm afraid you are missing a lot of colors with your method. I think of dark and light colors, indeed, the way you are paritionning the range of values for each octet R, G and B makes it impossible to get close to 0xFFFFFF and 0x000000. I think there are still many "not gray" colors in there.

Comment: @leaf, true, I added an alternative for allowing more kinds of colors to be generated. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: both solutions will bias the probability of some colors relative to others, among acceptable colors; moreover, they do more more work than a simple rejectance based method would do...

Answer (score 1):

gray Color spectrum is: `R` = `G` = `B`

edited code:

```
var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
    if (color.length === 1)
    {
        color.concat('0');
    }
    console.log('#'+color+color+color);
```

sample: https://jsfiddle.net/6jjp17sx/1/

Comment: if I got it correctly, the OP wants to *exclude* greys

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes its random Can change range 0-255 to 45-170  its simple.

Comment: Yeah but suppose I included '#c8c8c8', it will exclude that but '#c8c8c9' to 'c8c8cf' are also shades of gray. How to exclude those?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way (preserving uniformity) is by simply rejecting them

```
do
{
  color = ...;
}
while( color[0]==color[2] && color[0]==color[4] &&
  color[1]==color[3] && color[1]==color[5] );
```

note that the probability of finding a grey color(in the sense of having the form #RRR) is `1/65536`, this will loop just ~1 times on average ...

Rejectance based sampling has the advantage of being general: if you change your mind later, you just need to change the rejectance criterion. Moreover, it's also fast as long as the rejectance probability is sufficiently small (but not *that* small, even with a probability of one-half the loop will evaluate just twice on average).

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to create an array of all grey shades.

on creating hex codes, check if it is in the array and perform your operations.

whole list of grey shades [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_shades.asp)

```js
let allGreyShades = ['#000000','#080808','#101010']
// actually there is lot more .. 3 just for demo purposes;

let colorGenerated = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

if(allGreyShades.indexOf(colorGenerated) == -1) {
 // your logic comes here
}
```

Comment: Yeah but suppose I included '#c8c8c8', it will exclude that but '#c8c8c9' to 'c8c8cf' are also shades of gray. How to exclude those?

Comment: I have an idea; find all hex codes given a range (Starting and ending hex code). using this ur issue can be solved. can u give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

I would extract and compare the three octets to see if they are the same. When random gives a shade of gray, I simply invert the green part in order to avoid calling random multiple times, but your strategy could be different depending on your needs :

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  paint(div, randomColorExceptGray());
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function paint (el, color) {
  var rgb = colorToRgb(color);
  el.style.backgroundColor = (
    "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")"
  );
}

function randomColorExceptGray () {
  var white = 0xFFFFFF;
  var random = Math.random();
  var color = Math.ceil(random * white);
  var rgb = colorToRgb(color);
  if (rgb[0] === rgb[1] === rgb[2]) {
    return color ^ 0x00FF00;
  } else {
    return color;
  }
}

function colorToRgb (color) {
  var R = (color & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
  var G = (color & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
  var B = (color & 0x0000FF);
  return [R, G, B];
}
```

```css
div{height:50px;width:50px;float:left;margin:0 10px 10px 0}
```

This solution is really clumsy though, it doesn't care about `0x000001` for example... Here is a better one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47616597/1636522.